# How to align the two div's in a div horizontally?

Tags: css

```html
<div>
   <div style="float: left; border: 1px solid green;">Left Text</div>
   <div style="text-align: center; border: 1px solid red;">Center Text</div>
</div>
```

Note: The first div always should be in left. The second div should be in center of the page.

Comment: The second `div` IS in the center of the page.. Also your question is ambigious at best take a look here for some pointers : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align horizontally the two inner divs into the parent one, don't use float.

Try to add

```
display: inline-block;
width: 45%; /* example */
```

And then text-align: center on the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not sure I understand your question completely, I think this is what you are looking for:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;
}
.center {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">Left Text</div>
    <div class="center">Center Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```